# Sending python script with arguments to Apache Livy

Tags: python, rest, apache-spark, pyspark, livy

I am trying to send python script with arguments to Apache Livy. Already I have a code which sends content of file (`file_content`) to Livy using following python code:

```
data = {
        'code': file_content
}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(host + '/sessions/' + session_number + '/statements', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Now I would like to send python script with arguments injected into file for example on unix system this would look like this:
`python add_two_numbers.py 1 2` but using Apache Livy. So far I was not successful with finding a solution. I would be thankful for any tips.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this..kuch appreciated if you can share the solution

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

for your case, livy json will be `"args": [1, 2]`

if your python command is like `python add_two_numbers.py --first 1 --second 2`

livy json will be `"args": ["--first=1", "--second=2"]`